# ASP.NET not showing CSS or JS works in VS2013 but not in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, iis, web-config

Okay literally have spent 14 hours trying to get this to work today. I have a asp.net web app in VB that was built with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate -- Everything works fine on localhost -- when I push to remote server the css styles and js don't load. I pushed site to a deb box I have running iis 6 and everything works fine. So I know issue isn't in code. and I'm not an IIS pro so any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say css and jss dont load - do you mean you get 404 error ? or do they get downloaded but not applied.  You can check it out via the Network tab in chrome debugger

Comment: Chrome is not installed on that server and unfortunately its a govt client so they wont install chrome.  the application loads and runs etc.. but none of the styles show on the page and none of the JS functions work.. and this is only happening on IIS 7.5 I've tried it on 4 diffent boxes running IIS 7.5 and same issues.. I've pushed it out to a virtural hosting account running IIS 6 and everything works as expected Styles and JS all work with no changes to web.config so has to be something in IIS 7.5 that is happening. I have no idea how IIS works other then basic stuff..

Comment: you could use F12 on IE, and start network traffic monitor.  or directly go to your JS/CSS resource by typing the full URL. if you get 404 error that means your server is not configured properly, perhaps MIME type issue.  You can try to fix that by manually setting the mimetype in your web.config file.  (Again this is not something that i would recommend for production but this will help you isolate the issue)

Comment: I'm sure its an issue with the way they have set up IIS 7.5 I just pushed it to another server with IIS 7.5 and works fine so just need to figure out what they don't have set up correctly.

Comment: ok using IE debugger shows the files are there.. just not applying to page but paths are correct..

Answer (score 0):

Okay after several hours I have found the answer.

When ASP.net is installed serve static content is not enabled by default

To turn this on, go to Start | Control Panel | Programs and Features | Turn Windows Features On or Off | Internet Information Services | World Wide Web Services | Common Http Features and check the Static Content box.

This can also be done via web.config file like so

```
<handlers>
       <clear />
        <add 
            name="StaticFile" 
            path="*" verb="*" 
            modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" 
            resourceType="Either" 
            requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    </staticContent>
```

I hope this helps anyone else that is having the same issue